# Return a list in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java

I want to return a list in a String Array List.

What I mean is if I have 10 objects, and want to print out Index 3-7 only, how do I do this?

The reason I ask is I have a collection of photos and if the user wants to return photos from date1 - date2 it will print out all the photos between those dates.

I am trying to use for each loops but not sure if I should use for-loops or while loops.

Thanks,

EDIT:

This is the method header I am trying to code:

```
public ArrayList<Photo> datedPhotos(String date1, String date2)
```

Comment: Using `subList` API from ArrayList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)

Comment: Do you have sample code that you’ve tried and isn’t working? Please clarify (using the code) where you’re stuck. At first your question sounds like you just need an introduction to the subList API, but then you bring up dates...

Comment: Unless the list is sorted, you are likely going to have to loop from the start to the end of the list, which suggest a `for-loop`, if they are sorted, then you need to find the first element which meets the criteria and loop till you find all the matching elements, which suggests a `while-loop`

Comment: Can you add your Photo class please?

Comment: I checked your previous questions, and noticed that you are persisting date as Strings. You should consider changing them to proper date type, and it will be easier to compare and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use date as Date type in java.
Then you can use a temp ArrayList to store photos from date1 to date2 using any loop

```
public ArrayList<Photo> datedPhotos(Date date1, Date date2)
 {
      ArrayList<Photo> temp=new ArrayList<Photo>();
      for(Photo photo:PhotoList)  //Here PhotoList is ArrayList of photos
      {
        if (/*Compare Dates using compareTo() method*/)
        temp.add(photo)
      }
      return temp;
 }
```

You can use java8 DateTime API for handling Date types

Answer (score 0):

The outline could be as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Photo> datedPhotos(String date1, String date2) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("<your-date-pattern>");
    Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(date1);
    Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(date2);
    ArrayList<Photo> filteredPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Photo photo : photoList) { // supposing that photoList is a field in your class, otherwise, you can pass it as the method parameter
        Date photoDate = photo.getDate();

        if((photoDate.after(startDate) || photoDate.equals(startDate) && (photoDate.equals(endDate) || photoDate.befor(endDate))) {
            filteredPhotos.add(photo);
        }
    }

    return filteredPhotos;
}
```